# errors using timer in C#

Tags: c#, service, namespaces, timer

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I did not have access to a Windows Services template so I downloaded one online.  I am trying to implement a timer into my project and I am getting the following errors.

> Error 1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs   19  23  windowsservice
>
> Error 2   Method must have a return type  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  19  29  windowsservice
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'timer' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  19  17  windowsservice
>
> Error 4   The name 'timer' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  23  4   windowsservice
>
> Error 5   The name 'OnElapsedTime' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  23  45  windowsservice
>
> Error 6   The name 'timer' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  24  13  windowsservice
>
> Error 7   The name 'timer' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs  25  13  windowsservice

Service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers; 

namespace SendFax
{
public partial class Service1: ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private timer = new Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 30000; // every 30 seconds
        timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    }
    }
    }
```

The namespace in both Program.cs and Service1.cs were named $SaveNamespace$. So, I changed both of them to SendFax.  Should these two files have separate namespace names?

I changed onElapsedTime to Tick.  Do the namespaces need to be named different on Program.cs and Service1.cs?

Comment: Can you add a comment to the line the error is complaining about (doubleclick the line in VS Express and it will bring you to the offending line). Guess: the line with `private timer`.

Comment: In addition, can you update your question with the download location you used for getting Service1.cs?

Comment: Can you fix some of the more obvious errors like "Method must have a return type" because I can't tell which is which.  Futhermore **OnElapsedTime** is not a valid event for the Timer class your looking for **Tick**.  These are careless mistakes....

Comment: I got it off the megaupload link on this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/52885523-e912-4d93-a09d-5333bb3e99c8     How could I correct the OnElapsedTime error?

Comment: Read my comment....The Event you want to subscribe to is **Tick** not **OnElapsedTime** trying to use code you don't understand will ALWAYS present problems like this.

Comment: You are still trying to subscribe to an event that does not exist.  Look at the MSDN documentation.  Update the list of errors I seriously doubt all of those are still valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the variable type here.

```
private timer = new Timer();
```

Try:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: That got it! But now I have. Error 1 Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs 29 10 windowsservice
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Private' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\bruser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsService\Service1.cs 29 2 windowsservice

Comment: private Timer timer = new Timer();

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
   timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 30000; // every 30 seconds
            timer.Enabled = true;

  }

     Private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
   // Execute your code here
    }

Comment: Please update your question....  The error explains itself.  The keyword is **private** not **Private**

Comment: Oh... I got you. Thanks.  I Will start updating my question.  Fixed the P.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the type of the `timer` variable. The proper syntax is like so:

```
 private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're declaring, `timer` does not have a datatype.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably other errors but you forgot to type your timer

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```